# JComboBox in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JTable created using a model, which is based on a matrix of objects.
For each row, I want to put in a specific column (the 5th) some information using a JComboBox. I have tried the following:

```
for(int i=0; i < n ; i++) {  
    .....  
    data[i][5] = new JComboBox(aux); // aux is a Vector of elements I wanna insert  
}  
table.setModel(new MyTableModel()); // MyTableModel() already takes into consideration the data[][] object
```

The problem is that `data[i][5] = new JComboBox(aux);` does not create a JComboBox object in that specific cell of the JTable, but pastes a code into the row. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add JComboBox to a specific cell in the JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426175/how-to-add-jcombobox-to-a-specific-cell-in-the-jtable)

Answer (score 9):

One way is to override the getCellEditor() method to return an appropriate editor. Here is an example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JFrame
{
    List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        // Create the editors to be used for each row

        String[] items1 = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox( items1 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
        editors.add( dce1 );

        String[] items2 = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox( items2 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
        editors.add( dce2 );

        String[] items3 = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox( items3 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
        editors.add( dce3 );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                    return editors.get(row);
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };
        System.out.println(table.getCellEditor());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableComboBoxByRow frame = new TableComboBoxByRow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit: code updated to use trashgod's suggestion.

Comment: Very succinct. As an alternative, consider `List<DefaultCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<DefaultCellEditor>(3)`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the example code before generics existed. I guess I should update it to be more current :)

Comment: On reflection, `List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(3)` may be better. It's more general, obviates the cast in `getCellEditor()` and allows the implementation to be changed. Sorry for the bum steer; still learning.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
 public void example(){  

      TableColumn tmpColum =table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
      String[] DATA = { "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 4" };
      JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(DATA);

      DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor=new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
      tmpColum.setCellEditor(defaultCellEditor);
      tmpColum.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer(comboBox));
      table.repaint();
   }


/**
   Custom class for adding elements in the JComboBox.
*/
class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        JComboBox combo;
        public CheckBoxCellRenderer(JComboBox comboBox) {
            this.combo = new JComboBox();
            for (int i=0; i<comboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
                combo.addItem(comboBox.getItemAt(i));
            }
        }
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            combo.setSelectedItem(value);
            return combo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This changes all cells in `tmpColum` into JComboBoxes. What if you only want to change a specific cell using its row and column?

Answer (score 1):

For the `JComboBox` to be disaplyed, you have to use a `TableCellRenderer`. Take a look at [*Using a Combo Box as an Editor*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox).

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, it's not to be used like you proposed.

You have to create a custom TableCellRenderer or TableCellEditor.
Then you can specify for which class it will be used:

```
JTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class<?> columnClass, TableCellRenderer renderer)
JTable.setDefaultEditor(Class<?> columnClass, TableCellEditor editor)
```

A detailed description can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

For a custom renderer in a specific row & column, you can simply use:

```
final int specialRow = 1;
final int specialColumn = 5;

JTable table = new JTable(myModel) {
   private TableCellEditor mySpecialCellEditor = new SpecialCellEditor( ... );

   public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
      int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
      int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
      if (modelColumn == specialColumn && row == specialRow ) {
         return mySpecialCellEditor;
      } else {
         return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you
I have been analysing all these examples you posted and others,on the internet.. but they dont fit.
I just need to create a JComboBox on a Specific place in the JTable, such as data[1][5] .
The box is already created,I just need to link it on that place.
In these examples I see they get a full column and create a JComboBox out of it, and I see nowhere how would they refer to a  specific place in the table, such as row-2, column-5...etc...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar where I need comboboxes on columns in certain rows.

```
    Integer boolInt[]  = {0,1};
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(boolInt);
    DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor=new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
    
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {//columns
            TableColumn tmpColum =table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j);
            JComboBox<Integer>(boolInt);
            tmpColum.setCellEditor(defaultCellEditor);
            tmpColum.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer(comboBox));
            table.repaint();
        }
```

Comment: This is "Thanks", right? Then please delete this. Or do you feel that with this you contribute any additional insight to answering the question at the top of this page? In that case please [edit] towards [answer].