# Combobox won't popout when clicked in JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a problem anyone can help me. This is my `JTable` and one column rendered in it have a combo box in its cell. Here is my problem in my table: it wont popup when I click the combo box. When I print, `table.getValueAt(row,column)`, it will get back the prev data of the cell not the data in combo box, and it doesn't show the combo box to let the user choose.

The code of the `JTable`:

```
public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table, TableColumn sportColumn) {
    // Set up the editor for the sport cells.
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    model.addElement("Snowboarding");
    model.addElement("Rowing");
    model.addElement("Knitting");
    model.addElement("Speed reading");
    model.addElement("Pool");
    model.addElement("None of the above");
    comboBox.setModel(model);
    sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    ComboBoxTableCellRenderer renderer = new ComboBoxTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setModel(model);
    sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}
```

[image]

Comment: here is the code  , its when the rendering done , if i can ask anothe question , i am adding data to the jtable from a database is there any thing to do with that ?

Answer (score 1):

[`TableRenderDemo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg) is a complete, working example as modified below.

[image]

1. To see that the editor updates the `TableModel`, enable debugging in `MyTableModel`.

   ```
   private boolean DEBUG = true;
   ```

   The result will be shown on the console:

   ```
   $ java TableRenderDemo
   Setting value at 0,2 to None of the above (an instance of class java.lang.String)
   New value of data:
       row 0:  Mary  Campione  None of the above  5  false
       row 1:  Alison  Huml  Rowing  3  true
       row 2:  Kathy  Walrath  Knitting  2  false
       row 3:  Sharon  Zakhour  Speed reading  20  true
       row 4:  Philip  Milne  Pool  10  false
   ```
2. Use one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17342917/230513) to let the table editor have the design of an ordinary `JComboBox`; the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348287/230513) using a `UIManager` icon is illustrated above.

   ```
   sportColumn.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){

       @Override
       public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
               boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
           JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
               value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
           label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("Table.descendingSortIcon"));
           return label;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: its the same thing ,  its working when i see demos  and touturials but its same thing in my code

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you describe.