# Can I use different combo boxes in the different cells of a TableColumn of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have seen this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

But it defines a single combo box for the entire column. I would like to define different combo boxes for the different cells of the column.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that there are n rows in the `JTable` and the i'th column of the `JTable` will be a column containing combo boxes. If I have a `ComboBox`[] comboBoxes, where comboBoxes.length == n, how can I resolve that comboBoxes[0] will be the content of the [0][i]'th cell of the `JTable`, comboBoxes[1] will be the [1][i]'th cell of the `JTable` and so on, comboBoxes[n - 1] will be the [n - 1][i]'th cell of the `JTable`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to the way in the tutorial posted, except instead of getting the column and setting the whole column do it just for the once cell.

Comment: You speak from my heart. But how does somebody do that?

Comment: Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256086/jcombobox-in-a-jtable-cell)

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not know how can I set the cell editor of a cell. I have seen in the example that a method was created along with the creation of the new variable, but I do not have the luxury to be able to do this when the object is constructed. Is there a way to link the object with the method later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still do not know how can I set the cell editor of a cell.

In the particular case of [`TableComboBoxByRow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256602/230513), the program first creates a series of editors in a `List<TableCellEditor>` named `editors` for later use. The program then overrides the `getCellEditor()` method of `JTable`, and it returns the desired editor for each row in the 
combo column. Note how the first three rows each get a different editor from the `List`, while the row four editor is just the default text field provided by the superclass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, getCellEditor overwriting it is. This was the missing piece of puzzle, it works like a charm! Thank you again.