# JComponent contains method does not work in the MouseEvent action of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent

I have a cell in `JTable` where a `JPanel` has located in it. `JPanel` has 2 labels inside it. I want to do different action when left label is clicked, and I want to make another operation when right action is clicked. I do not want to use `TableCellEditor`, it makes my code so complicated. Becase my cell values has a range of type.

I write following code to get selected component from mouse event, but with no success. I tried also `SwingUtilies.convertMouseEvent`, but it did not change anything. What is the problem with below code? Why `JComponent` contains method does not check mouse point.

```
contSimTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(event)) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                JTable target = (JTable) event.getSource();
                int row = contSimTable.getSelectedRow();
                int column = contSimTable.getSelectedColumn();
                /**
                 * convert from view colum to model.It is column index
                 * which is stored in table model
                 */
                int modelColumn = target.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                Object clickedCell = contSimTable.getValueAt(row, modelColumn);
                if (clickedCell instanceof JPanel) {
                    boolean isSecond = false;
                    JLabel a = (JLabel) ((JPanel) clickedCell)
                        .getComponent(0);

                    JLabel b = (JLabel) ((JPanel) clickedCell)
                        .getComponent(1);
                    if (a.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                        isSecond = false;
                    }
                    //                                                      
                    if (b.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                        isSecond = true;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your row/column is selected when the listener executes? Do you do that in some other part of your code?

Comment: When I debug code,  ı see that row and column is selected

Comment: Is `target` and `contSimTable` the same `JTable` instance? Or perhaps `contSimTable` is a `TableModel`?

Comment: target and contsimtable is same jTable instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is the correct approach. There are a number of ways to address different data types:

- By default, as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).
- By `TableColumn`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).
- By the type-token returned from `getColumnClass()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).
- By overriding `getCellEditor()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256602/230513).

For more specific guidance, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that typifies your chosen approach.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513) containing a panel with multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the MouseListener to the JTable. It would be much easier for you to add the needed listeners to the single JComponent directly.

Example

How you are doing it:

```
contSimTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) 
    {
         //Coordinate calculation for the jlabels
    }
    });
```

Try:

```
jlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) 
    {
         //Do stuff here
    }
    });
```

Comment: As I commented, I do not want to deal with custom table cell editor. I tried this.But I get other problems  meanwhile clicking other cells(table.getselectedRow return -1 for  mouseevent of table))

Comment: Hi, I found something weird. I just tested your code. It looks like your mouseClicked method is not correct. Try mousePressed(..).

Answer (score 0):

After clarifying in the comments that `contSimTable` and `target` variables are the same `JTable` instance I believe that the statement `int modelColumn = target.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);` seems to be the cause for the misbehaviour you encounter.

The `JTable.getValueAt()` method already calls `convertColumnIndexToModel()` and `convertRowIndexToModel` behind the scenes so you should probably not call those methods yourself. (Btw if for some reason you had to convert to the model manually you should do the same for the row right?).

Though it is not clear what you are trying to do since your table seems to store components in its model (a `JPanel`) instead of data. If you are trying to customize the display of your cells you should use a [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and if you want to edit the cell you should use a `TableCellEditor` as already suggested by others. Ideally your program should interact with the `TableModel` only, which would then take care of notifying the table to re-draw itself during data changes.

I hope this helps